# Create an array of attributes from a list of objects

Tags: javascript, json

What I'm trying to do is read this array of objects below and from there build a list with the free values.

```
const data = [
  {
      "house01": {
        "free": 6
      },
      "house02": {
        "free": 2
      },
      "house03": {
        "free": 1
      },
  }
]


console.log(data.map((item) => item.free))
```

Response

```
[undefined]
```

Expected response

```
[6, 2, 1]
```

What I don't understand is why the result doesn't go as expected.

Comment: Why is the data structured like that? An array of objects with one object with consecutive numbers as keys. Why nit something like `const data = { houses: [{ "free": 6 }, { "free": 2 }] }` with an additional `houseId` property in each house object, if required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two iterations, one for the array and another for the object's values to get the wanted property.

```js
const data = [{ house01: { free: 6 }, house02: { free: 2 }, house03: { free: 1 } }];

console.log(data.flatMap(item => Object.values(item).map(({ free }) => free)));
```

By having unwanted keys, you need to add a filtering and take the entries to get the key as well.

```js
const
    data = [{ house01: { free: 6 }, house02: { free: 2 }, house03: { free: 1 }, dontcountthisdata: "USA" }],
    unwanted = ['dontcountthisdata'];

console.log(data.flatMap(item => Object
    .entries(item)
    .filter(([key]) => !unwanted.includes(key))
    .map(([, { free }]) => free)
));
```

Comment: What if I have an object that I don't want to be counted in this flatmap ()? Something like that:

[
   {
       "house01": {
         "free": 6
       },
       "house02": {
         "free": 2
       },
       "house03": {
         "free": 1
       },
       "dontcountthisdata": "USA",
   }
]

Comment: do you have only one or more unwanted properties?

Comment: More than one unwanted properties

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick question, do you know any functions that return data in the order they appear in the list? When I use this function that you created they appear in a different order from the parent list, for example the right would be [6, 2,1] but something like [2, 6, 1] appears

Comment: the keys of an object are usually sorted by index like numbers sorted, first, then strings/other numbers in insertation order and at last symbols in insertation order.